# How to drill through multiple has many/belongs to associations in a where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations, where-clause

I have the following ActiveRecord model associations:

> A User has many Goals; a Goal has many Objectives; an Objective has many Tasks; a Task has many Requirements.

I'm building an API where I want the `/api/requirements` endpoint to return all of the Requirements for a particular User, by drilling through the associations defined above. However, I'm having trouble writing the `where` clause. This is what I have so far:

```
Requirement.where('tasks.objectives.goals.user_id = ?', user.id)
```

This doesn't work though. I can't seem to jump through the associations to get to the user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:-

Requirement.joins(:task => {:objective => :goal}).where('goals.user_id = ?', user.id)

Comment: Thanks! One must be careful to use singular nouns for the `joins`, and plural for the `where`.